# XNA Game State Management reference assigning

Tags: c#, reference, xna, state

Recently I started using **Game State Management** (details: [create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management)) which is great template for simple games made in XNA.

I've been analyzing its implementation for a few days and I have doubt in **LoadingScreen.cs** in this method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The constructor is private: loading screens should
/// be activated via the static Load method instead.
/// </summary>
private LoadingScreen(ScreenManager screenManager, bool loadingIsSlow,
                      GameScreen[] screensToLoad)
{
    this.loadingIsSlow = loadingIsSlow;
    this.screensToLoad = screensToLoad;

    TransitionOnTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5);
}
```

I don't understand why there is reference assigning: `this.screensToLoad = screensToLoad;`. Why isn't something like a `.Clone()` method used instead?

**[edit]**

OK... I think my problem is not XNA or Game State Management I prepared piece of code with explanation what is my doubt all about.

Here comes the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace test
{
    public class a
    {
        public int number = 3;
    }

    public class b
    {
        public a tmp;

        public void f(a arg)
        {
            tmp = arg; // (*?*) isn't it dangerous assigning?
        } 
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            b temp_b = new b();

            {// (*!*) CODE BLOCK COMES HERE:
                a temp_a = new a();
                temp_b.f(temp_a);
                temp_a.number = 4;
            }

            // TROUBLE EXPLANATION:
            // We are outside of code block which I marked with (*!*)
            // Now reference 'temp_a' is inaccessible. 
            // That's why line of code which I marked with (*?*) is dangerous.
            // We saved 'temp_a' which is no longer accessible in 'temp_b' object.
            // 
            // Now computer's memory pointed by reference, which is saved in 'temp_b.tmp' (and was saved in 'temp_a'),
            // can be overriden by code which comes somewhere below this comment (or even in another thread or process).
            //
            // I think the same situation is in XNA GSM's piece of code.
            // The only solution in my opinion is deep copy (AFAIK .Clone() can be implemented as shallow or deep copy).

            Console.WriteLine(temp_b.tmp.number); // result is 4
                                                  // because we copied reference
                                                  // For me it's strange that this line was printed. As I mentioned above
                                                  // memory intended for 'temp_a' could be reused and overwritten.
        }
    }
}
```

And for convenience same code here: [ideone.com/is4S3](http://ideone.com/is4S3).

I put questions and doubts in above code (see comments).

Comment: Why would you expect this? Clone takes time, reference assignment (practically) does not.

Comment: It's not good argument. If it were we wouldn't use **Clone()** at all. What for? It's more time and memory consuming.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that's purely down to the taste of whoever wrote the library, but it's probably because the `Load()` method has the following signature:

```
public static void Load(ScreenManager screenManager, bool loadingIsSlow,
                        PlayerIndex? controllingPlayer,
                        params GameScreen[] screensToLoad)
```

Note that `screensToLoad` is defined using the `params` keyword.  That means you're expected to call it like this:

```
LoadingScreen.Load(manager, false, null, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5);
```

Where s1 ... sN are the screens being loaded.

In this use case, the calling code doesn't actually have a reference to the array anyway, so making a clone of it would be a pointless waste of time and memory.  The chances of its contents being changed out from under you are rather small.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to do a shallow copy of screensToLoad (copying only the array), but as pointed in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10446418/221933), not doing it typically won't cause trouble.

Making a deep copy would be wrong. Screens are stateful objects, and if you duplicate it them users won't get the effect they would typically expect. For instance, all handlers registered to the original screens after a call to `Load` would be registered to "dead" screens, as the `ScreenManager` would be holding the copies, not the originals.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer but I still don't know why there is no problem with variable's scope. I simplified my problem in my first post's edit. It's 100% equivalent of XNA problem. I would be grateful if you could answer doubts from my question **edit** referring to them.

Comment: This constructor is private, it is called via `Load`. In the typical use case, people won't call `Load` with an array, but with a comma-separated list of arguments. The untypical case where an array is passed instead is indeed problematic. The author of the sample just did not care about the untypical case.

Answer (score 0):

A screen object is created to be managed by the screen manager...

Has no sense made a clone because the original screens  will become useless...

Maybe it were better that the screen manager was a factory, creating the screen by type and returning a id or the screen to be initialized with custom params...

but I think that this code comes from a sample to learn, and should not expect to have a complicated code...